# Why is all my flag history gone?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags

Just since an hour or so, my "helpful flags" count on Ask Ubuntu appears to be reset, and only on AU where I had about 400+ helpful flags raised. On other SE sites, it seems all fine though.

I also see Q&A appearing in the mod tool which I already flagged earlier on. Opening the flags summary page for my user account shows only the flags I added in the last hour or so.

Is this a glitch? Please restore my flag history.

[image]

(A few moments later after I flagged some posts, it is now raised)

[image]

I'd swear I had the counter at **405** earlier on. On SO, this is still fine:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Major changes to the flagging system are coming/taking place, including how they are stored in the database. This bug was fixed about an hour ago. See the MSO report: [Flag count is missing from profile pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185866/flag-count-is-missing-from-profile-pages).

Answer (score 8):

#### And it's all back.

Just noticed everything seems fine again.

[image]